# Add space after every 4th character in an input string WHILE writing it?

Tags: c#, string, format

I am aware that questions like these have been asked before here, however I could not find one which explains how to do this LIVE while the user is inputting a string in a textbox. This is regarding a windows form app in C#.

Here is my current code:

```
for (int i = 4; i <= input.Length; i += 4)
{
    input = input.Insert(i, " ");
    i++;
}
```

This does not work, as it continues to add spaces after every keypress. I have this for-loop run on a non-return keypress.

Comment: You should probably check that there isn't already a space before trying to add one. E.g. if the user types a space, or if you've already run this method, then you don't need to add it again

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came to, I think that if you adapt the "Console." stuff to window forms, it will work.

```
 string text = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) //Change 50 for whatever size you want
    {
        switch (i % 5) //every time 'i' is a multiple of 5 it will write a blank space
        {
            default:
                text += Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                break;
            case 0:
                Console.Write(" ");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to explain how it works?

Comment: Like -- what's with the magic numbers? What's 50 do? why 5?

Comment: I don't think this can be adapted to Windows form. The event of formatting the text triggers on a text change within the textbox, meaning that it will trigger over and over again and will keep adding spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. For anyone browsing this thread years in the future, here is what I did:

```
if (input.Replace(" ", String.Empty).Length % 4 == 0 && input[input.Length - 1] != ' ')
{
    input += ' ';
}
```

This adds spaces where they are needed and makes sure to not cause an infinite loop of adding spaces and triggering the TextChanged event.

Comment: And what happens when the user users the arrows or the mouse?

Comment: @NetMage nothing good. But for my purpose this is sufficient. It works well enough, although far from perfect.